# PHPとMSSQLServerで　ページインデックス付のテーブルを表示したい

Tags: php

皆様　いつもご親切なご支援を誠にありがとうございます。
今回標題の件を達成する上で、以下記事
https://qiita.com/ShibuyaKosuke/items/0c5c6df1fac218fbca38
を参考にさせて頂いておりますが、こちらはDB=MYSQLが故　達成できていることなのか、当方の応用能力がないためにMSSQLServerに適用できないのか判断できない状況です。

====質問====
記事の中にある以下ソース部分をコメントアウトすることで、一応に動作します。
（全体でたった5件という判断が行われた表示をしますが、ページインデックスも表示されました。）
このコメントアウトをとってしまうと、MSSQLServerから”'LIMIT' 付近に不適切な構文があります。”というエラーが返ってきており、画面は正常に動作を終えることができないようです。
・この部分では一体何をやっているいるのでしょうか？
・またそれはMYSQLにのみ適用できる機能なのでしょうか？MSSQLServerに適用できるものでしょうか？

毎度のことで申し訳ございませんが、皆様のお力添えをお待ち申し上げております。

```
// LIMITが設定されているとき
if (!is_null($limit)) {
    $start = getCurrentPage() * $limit;
    $statement .= sprintf(' LIMIT %d, %d', $start, $limit);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($statement);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    $recset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: LIMIT句は,sqlserverには,有りません。同じようなことをするにはBETWEENとかで件数を絞るのが良いかと思います。

Comment: @yyz いつも大変御世話になっております。MYSQLが全く経験のない者で、PHPかDBMS側の問題か一切特定できていなかったので
ご見解は当方にとって大変貴重なものでした、ありがとうございました。
そういうことでしたか．．．sprintf関数で得たい内容をようやく推察することが理解でき、MSSQLに適用できる気になりました。
最終的にまた報告を改めたいと思います。

Comment: @yyz 仰られるとおりBETWEEN句の代替で無事問題を回避できました、いつもありがとう御座います、本当に助かりました。